# Variadic templates and std::bind

Tags: c++, templates

Given the following templated function, how can I change it to take advantage of variadic templates?  That is to say, to replace std::bind placeholders with a variadic parameter instead of P1 and P2?  At the moment I have one of these functions per arity, with arity zero having no P parameter, up to arity 9 having P1 to P9 parameters.  I was hoping to collapse this into a single function if possible.

```
template<typename R, typename T, typename U, typename P1, typename P2>
void Attach(R (T::*f)(P1, P2), U p)
{
    AttachInternal(p, std::bind(f, 
                                p.get(), 
                                std::placeholders::_1, 
                                std::placeholders::_2));
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I think you would have to create a parameter pack holding the placeholders, using `sizeof...(P)`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can (partially) specialize `std::is_placeholder` for specializations of a custom template. This way, you can introduce a placeholder generator via the usual `int_sequence` technique.

From [func.bind.isplace]/2

> The implementation shall provide a definition that has the `BaseCharacteristic` of `integral_constant<int, J>`
>   if `T` is the type of `std::placeholders::_J`, otherwise it shall have a `BaseCharacteristic` of `integral_constant<int, 0>`. A program may specialize this template for a user-defined type `T` to have a `BaseCharacteristic` of `integral_constant<int, N>` with `N > 0` to indicate that `T` should be treated as a placeholder type.

The usual `int_sequence`:

```
#include <cstddef>

template<int...> struct int_sequence {};

template<int N, int... Is> struct make_int_sequence
    : make_int_sequence<N-1, N-1, Is...> {};
template<int... Is> struct make_int_sequence<0, Is...>
    : int_sequence<Is...> {};
```

The custom placeholder template and specialization of `is_placeholder`:

```
template<int> // begin with 0 here!
struct placeholder_template
{};

#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

namespace std
{
    template<int N>
    struct is_placeholder< placeholder_template<N> >
        : integral_constant<int, N+1> // the one is important
    {};
}
```

I'm not sure where to introduce the `1`; the places I considered are all not optimal.

Using it to write some binder:

```
template<class Ret, class... Args, int... Is>
void my_bind(Ret (*p)(Args...), int_sequence<Is...>)
{
    auto x = std::bind(p, placeholder_template<Is>{}...);
    x( Args(42)... );
}

template<class Ret, class... Args>
void my_bind(Ret (*p)(Args...))
{
    my_bind(p, make_int_sequence< sizeof...(Args) >{});
}
```

Usage example of the binder:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(double, char, int) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }
void bar(bool, short) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }

int main()
{
    my_bind(foo);
    my_bind(bar);
}
```

Comment: I wonder why such a template `placeholder_template` isn't in the Standard.

Comment: Maybe because `std::integer_sequence` is only C++14 ?

Comment: @MatthieuM. There is only an implementation-defined number of (standard) placeholders. I'd guess that a placeholder template could generally be useful, as you can reliably create a certain number of placeholders (even w/o the integer sequence technique).

Comment: I completely agree, and besides the issue of explicitly naming them there is also the issue that even small pack expansions are more easily realized with a real pack expansion than simulating it via successive specializations or an attempt at recursion.

Comment: OK, thanks for that.  It's interesting from a technical perspective, but I'm not sure I'm going to use it because it's a bit too advanced and it'll make my code harder to maintain for others.

Comment: I was just wondering: Why the placeholders use `int` instead of `std::size_t`? I think the latter is more appropiate.

Comment: @Manu343726 *shrug* There's no need to have (at least) 65535 possible arguments instead of 32767. Some committee members are also unhappy with the usage of unsigned types for anything but bit-twiddling. (Maybe you could look into a StdLib implementation or ask it as a separate question; I don't have a definite answer.)

Comment: This is extremely helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to propose a more simple solution to the problem to bind a member function to a variable number of placeholders:

```cpp
template<typename R, typename T, typename U, typename... Args>
std::function<R(Args...)> Attach(R (T::*f)(Args...), U p)
{
    return [p,f](Args... args)->R { return (p->*f)(args...); };
};
```

A simple example of the usage looks like that

```cpp
class CrazyAdd
{
public:

    CrazyAdd(double val)
    : m_crazyPart(val)
    {}

    double add(double a, double b)
    {
        return a+b+m_crazyPart;
    }

private:
    double m_crazyPart;
};

void main() {

    CrazyAdd myAdd(39);

    // Create a function object that is bound to myAdd
    auto f = Attach(&CrazyAdd::add, &myAdd);

    // Call the function with the parameters    
    std::cout << f(1,2) << std::endl;   // outputs 42
}
```

Personally I think that's another good example why Scott Meyer recommends lambdas instead of std::bind.

Comment: Finally, after a few days, full of searching I finally found a working solution! Thank you!!!