# how to check if function exists

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, macros

I want to implement my own `std::make_unique` function with the function being part of std namespace. I know this helper function is added to C++14 but I do not have it in C++11. So, I want to check it with some C++11 template magic (couldn't find any options with macros) to check if a function exists inside the `std` namespace and if it doesn't define it on my own. Is that possible? I don't even know where to start.

Comment: It's not possible from inside the program itself. You can however use tools like [autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/) or [cmake](http://www.cmake.org/) to check for functions *before* the build, and define preprocessor macros depending on the results of the checks.

Comment: Why do you think it should be in `std` ?

Comment: You might want to consider to always call your own function, and have that function dispatch to make_uniq or your own, depending on of std::make_uniq exists (detected via sfinae)

Comment: @MSalters because I wanted to be able to use `std::make_unique`, not something of my own that wraps around it. @PlasmaHH's after you comment, I am thinking of changing my "beliefs" on this particular code design.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best bet is to use the standard `__cplusplus` macro which, for C++11, is `201103L`. For C++14 onwards it will be a different value to this.

Answer (score 6):

You *cannot* add a new function to the `::std` namespace. You are only allowed to add specializations of *existing* templates, and even then only for your own types.

Comment: What prevents me from doing `namespace std { foo(); }`?

Comment: Just because you are not *allowed* to do it doesn't mean you *can't*.

Comment: @Paranaix: That your program becomes non-conforming, that a compiler detecting that might reject it, or it might do *anything* at all... @ Daniel: Yes, the *cannot* is in italics for a reason.

Comment: @DanielFrey see http://stackoverflow.com/q/8513417/819272 Of course, you are likely to get away with it unless a compiler checks against the entire list of allowed names in `std`

Comment: I doubt compiler would check for any additional library dependency. I have stumbled upon a post here regarding making a `std::bind` to bind placeholders automatically. Ill find it in a second

Comment: found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192659/variadic-templates-and-stdbind. I am actually using something similar to it in my post and I haven't gotten any problems on LLVM and GCC. Lets hope MSVC doesn't cry about it. I like obeying c++ rules but in some specific situations (not my original post though. breaking a rule for that isn't worth it IMO - I didn't know if there was a rule about it earlier) breaking those rules might solve a specific problem, like the link above.

Comment: @Gasim: I don't quite understand the point of the comments. We do agree that it is against what the standard guarantees, right?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas yes. sorry couldn't explain my thoughts cleaner.

Comment: @Gasim you can introduce *specializations* into `std` for types dependent on your own types.  You cannot introduce anything else into `std` without invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: @Yakk the compiler still has to actively check against this for anything bad to happen. In practice copying, say, C++14 features from working papers into `namespace std` is unlikely to crash your program until your Standard Library itself defines the features. Although the proper way is to make your own `namespace cpp14` and work from there, and upgrade when your system has.

Comment: @TemplateRex I can think of many ways this could cause bad things to happen without active checks.  The feature is added without the version being updated, possibly with some differences. The compiler implements `std` "headers" as non-plain C++ code for optimization purposes, so your are interacting with something that only *looks* like a C++ namespace when you `std::`. People reading your code see `std::make_unique` in 4 years time and think it is C++1y's `make_unique`, but the standard shifted over that time, and now your code is unmaintainable.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an anwser but I want to point out that the committee is considering (see [n3694](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3694.htm)) the generic question: How a programmer could determine whether an implementation has a particular feature (e.g. `std::make_unique`) or not?

Currently, the best we have is the macro `__cplusplus` (as per [Bathsheba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2380830/bathsheba)'s [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21382776/1137388)) but as explained in [n3694](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3694.htm) this doesn't give the fine grain that programmers might need. (The OP's question is an example of this need.)

Answer (score 1):

Introducing `std::make_unique` yourself is undefined behavior, period.  There is no safe way to do it.  On top of that, it is also inadvisable -- the advantage you gain is small, and the maintenance and code understandability costs are high.

What more, the odds are your `make_unique` will not match whatever gets published exactly, so your code will have a strange version dependency.

A better plan is to define your own `make_unique` somewhere else in your own utility namespace.  If C++1y is active, you could `using std::make_unique` import it instead of your own `make_unique`.

This keeps your code standards compliant.  It should also be clear to users of `utility::make_unique` that it isn't guaranteed to be identical to C++1y's `make_unique`.

This also lets you punt the problem of detecting `std::make_unique` until after it is standardized, and then deciding if it matches the interface you ended up implementing.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <memory> // std::shared_ptr, std::unique_ptr

// C++11 check doesn't work in Visual Studio 2013/2015 properly because they are not fully C++11 compliant.
// https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/763051/a-value-of-predefined-macro-cplusplus-is-still-199711l
#ifndef WIN32
// C++11 Check
#if __cplusplus < 201103L
#error This library needs at least a C++11 compliant compiler.
#endif // >= C++11
#endif // WIN32


namespace std {

  // Note: despite not being even C++11 compliant, Visual Studio 2013 has their own implementation of std::make_unique.
#ifndef WIN32
#if (__cplusplus >= 201103L && __cplusplus < 201402L)
  // Define std::make_unique for pre-C++14
  template<typename T, typename... Args> inline unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args&&... args) {
    return unique_ptr<T>(new T(forward<Args>(args)...));
  }
#endif // C++11 <= version < C++14
#endif // WIN32

} // namespace std
```