# Getting undeclared args when trying to bind std::function using parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I'm trying to create a variadic template class that looks like this :

```
template <class... Args>
class Message
{
    private:

        std::function<void(Args...)> _function;
    public:
    //stuff

};
```

I want to have an option to bind so the user can bind any function (with corresponding arguments) when he wants. I've tried this approach (this function is a part of the `Message` class, so `Args...` comes from the template argument of the class):

```
    template<class T>
    void Message::bindFunction(void(T::*function)(Args... args), T* ownerPtr)
    {
        //This doesn't work
        _function = boost::bind(function,args, ownerPtr);
    }
```

However the above doesn't work, I've tried to create the tuple from the args in the bind function, but the compiler keeps saying:

```
<args_0> undeclared identifier.
```

(If I pass more arguments it changes)

From the user's point of view it should look like this:

```
class Foo
{
public:

    void test2(int a, float b, double c) 
    {  
        std::cout << "bla";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;

    Message<int,float,double> Mess;

    Mess.bindFunction(&Foo::test2, &f);
}
```

I've seen a lot of articles talking about forwarding the parameters, however most of the answers confuse me more than I am already with different template structures without explaining them.

Comment: You're already using C++11; a lambda would be more straightforward than `boost::bind` (or `std::bind`, which also exists).

Comment: @chris I know about the existence of the std::bind, the use of boost::bind was inteded as I wanted to create functors to member functions.

Comment: @Pins, `std::bind` also works for member functions. In fact, it's one of the examples on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind). Regardless, hooking up variadics to either is painful at best unless [`std::bind_front`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0356r2.html) makes it through. There's a [C++ Weekly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZlHi8txU4aQ) video on avoiding `bind` with lambdas, but it sounds like some extra variadic template material might be beneficial.

Comment: @chris In fact i was using std::bind before, however had some troubles with it when experimenting with linux platform (cannot remember the issue), tried the boost::bind and then decided to stick with it. Will check the bind_front.

Comment: @chris `std::bind_front` successfully made it through LEWG (Library Evolution Working Group) last week in Albuquerque.

Comment: @chris didn´t notice your note about lambdas and bind, thanks for that and also for this helpful video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a lambda because they're much nicer ([Live Demo (C++11)](https://wandbox.org/permlink/snVIxHshxMhCTK4O)):

```
template<class T>
void bindFunction(void(T::*function)(Args...), T* ownerPtr)
{
    _function = [function, ownerPtr](Args... args)
    {
        (ownerPtr->*function)(args...);
    };
}
```

We are capturing the function pointer and pointer to instance of the class with `[function, ownerPtr]` in the lambda declaration.

The lambda accepts a list of arguments whose types are specified in the variadic template for the `Message` class: `Args... args`.

Internally we call the function using our instance with the `(ownerPtr->*function)` syntax, and then pass in the arguments by expanding the parameter pack `(args...)`

To call the function you might write something like this:

```
void callFunction(Args&&... args)
{
    _function(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

We use [perfect forwarding](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) to pass our arguments to the `std::function<void(Args...)>` member.

Comment: I´m surprised how handily the lambda works here, now it works great, thanks.

Comment: @Pins: It would have been exceptionally difficult with `bind` because a variadic placeholder does not exist [so you'd have to write your own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21193316/27678)